# Error in strcmp C++?

Tags: c++

I have written the following code to compare two strings. but the output is wrong even when both strings are same, or 1st is greater than 2nd. can anyone guide me where is the error?

```
// String Conversion Functions
/* Standard Library (to be added): string.h*/

/*Prototype: int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
Description: Compares string s1 to s2. Returns a negative
             number if s1 < s2, zero if s1 == s2 or a 
             positive number if s1 > s2.*/

#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];
    int result;

    cout<<"Please enter first string: ";
    cin>>string1;

    cout<<"Please enter second string: ";
    cin>>string2;

    cout<<'\n';

    result = strcmp(string1, string2); //answer should be in int type variable
    //using if statements to compare different cases.
    //int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
    if(result > 1)
    {
        cout<<"1st string is greater than 2nd string"<<endl;
        //function returns a +ve number if s1 > s2.
    }
    else if(result == 0)
    {
        cout<<"1st string is equal to 2nd string"<<endl;
        //function returns 0 if s1 == s2.
    }
    else //if result < 1
    {
        cout<<"1st string is less than 2nd string"<<endl;
        //function return a -ve number if s1 < s2.
    }
}
```

Also, I read the similar posts but didn't get any solution to the above error.

Comment: `result > 1` should be `result > 0`

Comment: does it compare the number of characters in two different strings ?

Comment: Yes, it does. If they have different numbers of characters, they're not equal.

Comment: I tried your program, it works correctly when the strings are the same.

Comment: That's not proper C++; it should be `int main()` to be valid.

Comment: when I enter the same number of character, like 'hi' in s1 and 'me' is s2, it still says s1 is greater than s2. whereas length is same.

Comment: i am confused between the two terms, length and number of characters.

Comment: It does a lexicographical comparison (alphabetical order). Length isn't important unless a short string is the prefix of a long string and then the longer string is "greater".

Comment: means they can only be equal if they are word to word same ?

Comment: Correct, same characters and length means `strcmp` would return 0.

Comment: ok got it. thank you for guiding. that was helpful :)

Comment: sorry, just one more question, does it compare white spaces also? because if i include white spaces it s1, then it shows the result without asking s2.

Comment: A space character is just another `char` (ASCII value 32) so it would be compared too. Unfortunately `cin >> string1;` is formatted input. It sees whitespace as a delimiter so the first word goes into string1 and the second goes into string2. To read a complete line including whitespace into a `char` array use [`std::cin.getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) instead.

Comment: :) Thank you so much for these concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template:  `int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );`

strcmp() compares the C string str1 to the C string str2.

## 1. return value<0 :

the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2.

## 2. return value=0

the contents of both strings are equal.

## 3. return value>0

the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2.

The line `if(result > 1)` should be `if(result>0)` .